# NSAttributedString: letters interference with arabic font

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I used arabic font called: "Hafs", it is from here:
http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/download/UthmanicHafs1Ver09Font.zip

I used it to draw Ayat from Holy Quran, but some letters are interfered with others, as shown in picture:

[image]

how to represent right text without interference?

thanks

**EDIT:**

here is another photo from "Pages" application to show you the original text, i coloured words that corrupted in iOS simulator by red colour

[image]

**EDIT2:**
I set attributed strings follows:

1- i paste the string into TextView in the storyboard.

2- i wrote this code in the related viewcontroller:

```
        let font:UIFont! = UIFont(name: "KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS", size: 30)

    self.txt2.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: txt2.text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font])
```

Comment: I don't speak or read Arabic. Could you show what you are expecting exactly? Do you have the same picture without the interferences ? If you use these font elsewhere (let's say in Word.app), do you have the interferences? Are they linked to the font, or specific to iOS? What's the link to `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: thanks Larme, i added picture to represent original string

Comment: How did you set the text? Kerning issue?

Comment: see the EDIT2 please